# Is there an alogrithm that analyses mistakes and increses weighting of a certain subject based on the mistake?

Tags: algorithms, logic

I am building a program that analyses a students mistakes and that mistake is linked to a topic. Then the program gets the information that a certain person has made x mistakes on some topic. I want an algorithm that can sort out the topic that the student made the most mistakes in and give them a weighting. Then I want to use that data and plan a personalised revision plan for the student.
What is the best way of going about my goal? Thank you

Comment: Can you be more specific with what you are trying to do? This question is very broad, and currently it will be unlikely that you will get any helpful answer.

Comment: I want students to mark their past paper, the questions that they didn't get full marks on will be recorded. Then an algorithm sorts out the questions the got wrong by topic. Lesson topics. Then I will create another program that uses this data to make a revision plan for my students.

Comment: Maybe consider creating a "moving average" histogram for each student on each subject.  Anyways, I don't know how this question directly relates to computer science. You might want to define a bit more precisely and mathematically what a "personalized revision plan" would look like

Comment: Over x days for x days an hour, the order of the revision will originally be a uniform distribution. This distribution is then affected by the mistakes of the student.